# Is it really useful to use Css3pie for IE7+ for Css3?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I was searching for css3 option for IE and I came across [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) but after looking at the site I found that it is not compatible in IE at all.

[image]

Is it really useful to use Css3pie for IE ? if not then any other alternative

Comment: What version of IE is in your screenshot? The site does not look like that in any of my IE versions (6-9).

Answer (score 1):

It is really useful while using css3 properties in IE versions.

Remember that you need to enter the correct URL in the CSS - from where the html is loaded.

I've used it myself a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

I use css3pie very extensively in commercial environments for quite some time now. It's REALLY GREAT, but:

- Beware, its really slows down the browser, the ie6 & 7 js-engine isn't the fastest
- There are quite some edge-cases, where it won't work. READ THE "KNOWN ISSUES" and understand them, it will save you much time raging about not working code.

EDIT:

i work alot with ms-filters lately, it's a good alternative for the oder IE-Browser to keep up with modern browsers.